# Visually distinguish Bible quotes from other quotes

Tags: feature-request, bible-quotes, formatting

**This feature request on MSO: [Alternate (visually distinguishable) blockquote style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107440/159306)**

I'd like to see Bible quotes have a style of their own. They're very centric to the site, but we have a lot of other quotes, too. It would be great to be visually able to distinguish them.

A possible implementation would be to have a "hint" not unlike [the syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) used on SO. Something like

```
<!-- bible -->
> [**John 1:1 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%201:1&version=ESV)   
> <sup>1</sup> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
```

...and this would apply a CSS class that changes the background color of the blockquote.

---

### Example:

> [image: a sample of possible style]

Comment: This would have been so nice on to have for [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/why-is-elohim-translated-as-god-and-not-gods).  My first "quote" in there is *my* translation, which is definitely not biblical.

Comment: It'd also be nice to have the words of Our Lord in red.

Comment: @PeterTurner: I strongly disagree on its usefulness, but sure, there could be the option.

Comment: I like this, but I would suggest something simpler than <!--bible-->... such as maybe just using '>>'.  This could be implemented across all SE sites, as just an alternate quoting style. Perhaps other sites would have a use for alternate quoting styles--and we could just adopt one specific style for Bible quotes, and another for non-Biblical quotes.

Comment: We also need <blink>Blinking text!</blink>

Comment: Asked for the feature on MSO: [Alternate (visually distinguishable) blockquote style](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107440)

Comment: I think the block quotes are nice...but someone has to keep doing them for me. I've looked for the instructions for doing these, but can't find any reference for special text editing.  And, will the commands work on a MAC?

Comment: @newwings see http://christianity.stackexchange.com/editing-help . (you add `> ` in the beginning of a line to get blockquote. there's also a button for doing that)

Comment: @newwings I'd think there should be a link to that editing help page in the faq (now there's only one in the editor, as a small icon). I asked for a faq update in [Add link to /editing-help in FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107571)

Comment: dancek, Thanks...

Comment: Whatever happened to this feature request? There doesn't appear to be any "status-" tag on the linked MSO post to indicate SEI's response to the feature request. Perhaps the requested onebox feature for quoting Scripture could be combined with the unique formatting.

Comment: This could be problematic. What versions count as "the Bible"? Which canon? If I translate a passage from Greek or Hebrew myself, does that merit "Bible mode"? What if the translator is an expert? A non-expert?